# Adding a unique value to duplicate rows in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula

I have column A containing number ID. Each row in column A is Unique. 
I have column B containing City names. Each row In column B is unique. 
I have column C with duplicated city names from Column B. Duplications are random. One city is duplicated 2 times and another 10 times and so on.

What I would like to achieve is to assign the number ID from column A to duplicates in column C. Each different duplicate should have number Id in a form A1+1.

Notice that Alexander in Column D has value from A2, along with all duplicates. Alma is next with ID 499. Those are manual entries of course. 
Can anyone provide a formula to automate this?

I'm using Google Spreadsheets..

[image]

Comment: `Each different duplicate should have number Id in a form A1+1` so why is Alexander all `498`??

Comment: woulnd't it just be  Vlookup?

Comment: Obviously because all Alexander are the same values.. Right? Next different duplicate is Alma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use INDEX/MATCH, put this in D2 and copy down:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(C2,B:B,0))
```

Comment: This would add a +1?

Comment: @findwindow As I understand the OP wants the +1 every time the city changes, which is what the lookup table is doing.  so not reason for any math just a lookup.

Comment: I read it as each duplicate needs its own ID like 198+1, 198+2, etc. XD

Comment: The key word is; each ***different*** duplicate. Then  look at the line before `What I would like to achieve is to assign the number ID from column A to duplicates in column C.` so as the names change then add 1. not to each duplicate otherwise you are duplicating id numbers on different city names.  I may be wrong and we may never find out.

Comment: This works, I don't know is it the best way, but it saved my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I had to insert a column A with same values as Column C in order to get Vlookup to work, as I believe it indexes off of the 1st column always.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. Clear data from column D.
2. Paste `ArrayFormula` into cell D2.

Here's the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(OFFSET(C2,,,COUNTA(C2:C)),{B2:B,A2:A},2,0))
```